# Can I extend activity with asyncactivity?

Tags: android

What I am trying to accomplish is just have a single "activity" set up on the main page of my app, that literally does 3 things; 1)grabs real-local time/date, 2)grabs longitude/latitude, 3) and pushes all of these into a mysql database.

So my question is, do i need to extend activity or can i have a main class that just extends asynctask?

the reason for the asynctask would be to do the following, grab all the onPreexecute and then push data into mysql on "doInbackground"?

would this work?

Comment: What is asyncactivity??

Answer (score 0):

Your Main Activity should extend Activity, and when you want to run these functions, you can use Asynctask

**EDIT**
For instance:

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {

....
   TextView a, b, c; 
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        new GrabDataAndStore().execute();
    }

    public class Wrapper {
        public String data1;
        public String data2;
        public String data3;

    }
    private class GrabDataAndStore extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Wrapper> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
               //Open Dialog (loading)
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
              //Store
              Wrapper obj = new Wrapper();
              obj.data1 = (data gathered); 
              obj.data2 = (data gathered); 
              obj.data3 = (data gathered); 
              return obj;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Wrapper obj) {
             a.setText(obj.data1);
             b.setText(obj.data2);
             c.setText(obj.data3);
        }

    }

}
```

Notice that you can create a Wrapper class in order to pass values from doInBackground to onPostExecute.
This is not actually code, but clear instructions on how to proceed.
Hope it helps

Comment: Ok cool i understand that part because it is simpler to do with a button, but the situation  i am in is this, All i have on my xml side is just 3 textview fields where the time, and coordinates will appear after i execute methods to find those values. So in that case, what i am wondering is, can i run the asynctask class without having a "clickable" item? so instead of declaring the button as clickable after oncreate, all i will have is an asynctask that just does work in displaying my desired variables and then pushes them into webservice(php)

Comment: Yes, you can!

Instead of putting the code inside View.OnClickListener, you put it directly on onCreate

I have edited by answer so that it meets your requirements